# Display only 3 digits after decimal in DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I am trying to display only 3 digits after decimal point but I'm unable to do so.  I tried with [toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) method but I couldn't succeed.

Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Manoj1991/ebRXw/3623/).

HTML source code:

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>DATE</th>
            <th>CODE</th>
            <th>PRODUCT</th>
            <th>QUANTITY</th>
            <th>UNIT</th>
            <th>VALUE</th>
            <th>COUNTRY</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>01/01/2017</td>
            <td>84571001</td>
            <td>MACHININGCENTRESHORIZONTAL</td>
            <td>13</td>
            <td>NOS</td>
            <td>22.1382568</td>
            <td>JAPAN</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>03/01/2017</td>
            <td>84571001</td>
            <td>MACHININGCENTRESHORIZONTAL</td>
            <td>33</td>
            <td>NOS</td>
            <td>54.5104524</td>
            <td>JAPAN</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Why not just fix the output on the server? Instead of creating your HTML including number like `54.5104524` just round it on the server to this: `54.510` and insert that into your HTML. What server code are you using??

Comment: @Intervalia It's a static HTML page with lots of data

Answer (score 7):

The easiest is to use the built-in [**number helper**](https://datatables.net/manual/data/renderers#Number-helper) :

```js
columnDefs: [{
  targets: [5],
  render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number(',', '.', 3)
}]
```

Updated fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/ebRXw/3627/** Just an example, follow the link for details about all the options you can use along with the number renderer.

Answer (score 4):

you can define a custom renderer for one or multiple columns.

https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html)

```
$('#example').DataTable({
  responsive: true,

  columnDefs: [{
    targets: [5],
    render(v){
      return Number(v).toFixed(3) 
    }
  }]
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You could transform the cells' values before you apply `DataTable`.

Here is how you would do it, assuming the cells that need to be modified have the `hi` class.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#example .hi').each(function() {
        var num = $(this).html(); // get the content of the cell
        num = parseFloat(num); // transform it to a JavaScript number
        num = num.toFixed(3); // Limit the number of decimals to 3
        $(this).html(num); // Update the HTML content
    });

    $('#example').DataTable({
        responsive: true
    });

});
```